# Preserving password migrating from ASP.NET MVC 5 Identity to ASP.NET CORE Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm migrating from ASP.NET MVC 5 to ASP.NET CORE and trying to preserve the password so that users don't have to do a password reset. The MVC 5 app uses the Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core and in the ASP.NET CORE 2.1.1 app, it uses the built-in identity middleware.

When I generated a blank app, I was able to see the Identity tables:

```
dbo.AspNetRoleClaims (new)
dbo.AspNetRoles
Dbo.AspNetUserClaims
dbo.AspNetUserLogins
dbo.AspNetUserRoles
dbo.AspNetUsers
dbo.AspNetUserToken (new)
```

The schema is very similar to the MVC 5 version and I was able to manually update the schema while preserving the data including the the hashed password. However, when I try using the old password in the new app it doesn't work.

Is there a way to preserve the old password in the new app?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that you need to populate the NormalizedUserName field in dbo.AspNetUsers. For example if the UserName field is the email like "joe@somedomain.com" then create "JOE@SOMEDOMAIN.COM" in the NormalizedUserName field.